# Issue with template in structs struct in c++

Tags: c++, templates, struct

I have a struct in c++ which is something like this:

```
struct mystruct {
  template <typename T>
  T myproc() {
    std::cout << "RETURNING T";
    return T();
  }
};
```

Now this struct already exists(this is just a sample replica of exact struct) which I need to use. What I am trying to do is call the method `myproc()` like below:

```
    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
      mystruct dummystruct;
      int y = dummystruct.myproc();
      return 0;
    }
```

But it gives me this compilation error:

```
    error C2783: 'T mystruct::myproc(void)' : could not deduce template argument for 'T'
    see declaration of 'mystruct::myproc'
```

which I know is because the compiler has no way to know what is `T`.

So my question is, is the function declaration in struct proper? I don't think so but this code already exists in one of our old code, so I thought I should get others opinion on it.

So I know it is wrong, but if someone thinks its correct, please explain me how to use it then.

Comment: What are you trying to return from `myproc`?

Comment: Perhaps you meant `return T();`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm actually surprised that compiled (if it did initially?).

A template can be thought of as a type. You wouldn't return a type would you?

Your code can be looked as this.

```
struct mystruct {
  int myproc() {
    std::cout << "RETURNING INT";
    return int;
  }
};
```

Which isn't very valid.

If you want to return the default constructed value you are going to need to put parentheses.

```
struct mystruct {
  template <typename T>
  T myproc() {
    std::cout << "RETURNING T";
    return T();
  }
};
```

However, since the template parameter isn't deducible in the context of `s.myproc()` you're going to have to do `s.myproc<mytype>()`.

Comment: That's what i am trying to understand that whoever wrote the code, did he ever compiled it or not.

Answer (score 5):

`T` represents a type, such as `int`. Writing `return T;` will be the same as `return int;` when `T` is an `int`. Is `return int;` valid?

You can call your function template as: `dummy.myproc<int>();`. You have to tell it what `T` is by writing `<int>`. If however the function took a `T` argument then the compiler would be able to deduce what `T` is by seeing the type of the argument. For example `dummy.myproc(2.3)` would resolve as `T` being a `double` because `2.3` is a double.

Comment: yes but the funny thing is the procedure doesn't take any args. it does some type casting inside it. But still that type casting doesn't seem to resolve the issue with what T is unless i pass an argument as you suggested.

Comment: @PuneetMittal Can you show the actual code that has this problem?

Comment: Very nice explanation. It could not be explained any simpler than that.